# Can I save a manually cropped Image in Mathematica 10 without hard cropping?

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, image, interactive

In *Mathematica* 7 I was accustomed to a certain workflow:

1. Paste an image into a Notebook
2. Select **Actual Size** from the context menu, if necessary
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-drag the control points on the sides of the frame to soft-crop the image
4. Use **File** > **Save Selection As...** to save the cropped image to a file

This workflow is broken in version 10 because in it the entire *uncropped* image is saved whether I select the image itself or the enclosing Cell frame.

I can use the Crop Tool to crop the image, and that does allow me to save a cropped selection, but it hard-crops the image so that I cannot in the future change my crop selection.  (Of the Image in the Notebook.)

If the soft-cropped Image is part of a larger selection (but not merely a Cell containing only the image) the cropped part is indeed saved.  This works for saving sections of Notebooks but not images alone.

The only work-around I have found to both keep a soft-cropped Image and save a matching copy is to copy the Image and crop it again with the Crop Tool, then delete the copy.  This adds significant time to my workflow.

**Is this change a bug or a feature?**

**Is there another way to accomplish what I want interactively?**

Comment: I confirm that the described method works in v8.0.4 but in v.10.0.0 the entire *uncropped* image is saved. OS Win7 x64.

Comment: I would call it a "usability bug" for sure. One way to avoid making a copy in some scenarios is to use the crop tool, save the image and then press cmd+z (or corresponding undo shortcut on your OS.)

Comment: @Pickett Nice idea.  I normally operate on the assumption that *Mathematica* cannot undo, which was usually not far off the mark, but with multiple-undo I should start using it.  I suspect there may not be a better answer; consider posting that as one.

Comment: In 10.4 the cropped image is saved.

Comment: @Szabolcs Glad to hear it!  I think I should tag this as a bug; do you agree?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm confused.  I would expect Save Selection As... to save what I see on screen.  But I would expect Right Click -> Save Image As... to save the actual image, as it is, and preserve special properties (e.g. a 16-bit images should stay 16-bit and not get cropped by soft-cropping).  *Both* methods save the cropped image in 10.4

Comment: BTW in 10.3 it still saves as uncropped. This is a 10.4 change.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bug rather than a feature. One way to accomplish this that will work in some scenarios without making a copy of the image is to use the crop tool, save the image and then undo the cropping thus restoring the original image.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the described method does work in v.10.0.0 if the image is represented as `Graphics` object. To convert `Image` to `Graphics` one can use `Show`.

The reason why `Graphics` works is that the *soft crop* explicitly sets new `PlotRange` what can be seen by applying `Options` to the cropped image. But in the case of `Image` the `PlotRange` option exists only inside of the box representation in the Notebook and cannot be accessed by `Options`. Probably this is the direction where a workaround for `Image` or the source of the problem can be found.

### UPDATE

Here is a workaround for `Image`: after soft cropping the `Image` paste in the next `Input` cell and evaluate the following:

```
(SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell, 3]; 
Export["test.png", NotebookRead[]])
```

This exports cropped version of the `Image` shown in the Notebook. I do not understand however why the number `3` is needed (I have a little experience with `SelectionMove`). But it works.

Comment: Great!  Now I just need to find a fast way to convert an image into this kind of Graphics.  Unfortunately the **Graphics Editing** > **Paste into Graphic** command doesn't do it.  If you have time to look at that perhaps you can determine why.  Thanks.